# iOS: how to check if geo-location is still turned on?

Tags: ios

I'm using geo-location in my iPhone app. The battery drains faster even if I've used geo-location for few seconds, or if the app is in background.

How can I check if the geo-location service is still turned on on my iPhone device ? This is the code I've used:

...

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; // Create new instance of locMgr
    locationManager.delegate = self;

    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;


    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"locationManager startUpdatingLocation");

    reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:locationManager.location.coordinate];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];

    }

    ...

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{


}


- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    NSLog(@"locality %@", placemark.locality);
    location = [placemark.locality retain];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check and see what apps are using Location Services, go to the Settings app, under Location Services, there will be a grey arrow next to apps that have used it recently and a purple arrow next to apps that are actively using it.

[image]

To reduce battery usage you should turn off CLLocationManager as soon as you have a sufficiently good location for your needs and anytime your app resigns active:

```
-(void)appWillResignActive:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // pause GPS when not active to save battery
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Subscribe to the notification somewhere, such as in your view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(appWillResignActive:)
     name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```